# Sending jQuery UI Signature via Form

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery UI Signature (http://keith-wood.name/signature.html) inside a form to capture a signature.  This is working fine.  I am trying to find out how to pass that data to my action page via the form.  Here is what I have been working with:

```
 <script src="scripts/jquery.signature.js"></script>

 <script>
 $(function() {
 var sig = $('#sig').signature();
 $('#disable').click(function() {
    var disable = $(this).text() === 'Disable';
    $(this).text(disable ? 'Enable' : 'Disable');
    sig.signature(disable ? 'disable' : 'enable');
 });
 $('#clear').click(function() {
    sig.signature('clear');
 });
 $('#json').click(function() {
    alert(sig.signature('toJSON'));
 });
 $('#svg').click(function() {
    alert(sig.signature('toSVG'));
 });

 $('#sig').signature({guideline: true});


 });
 </script>



 <div id="sig"></div>
 <p style="clear: both;">
 <button type="button" id="disable">Disable</button> 
 <button type="reset" id="clear">Clear</button> 
 <button type="button" id="json">To JSON</button>
 <button type="button" id="svg">To SVG</button>
 </p>



 <input type="hidden" value="signature" name="sig_form">
```

Comment: add an event listener so that on submit of form it calls the `sig.signature` method. Populate a hidden input field with that outputted value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no plans on using AJAX, the simplest method is to create a hidden field for storing the jSON and set its value to the jSON.

```
<input type="hidden" name="signature" class="signature" value="">

$('form').submit(function() {
    $(".signature").val(sig.signature('toJSON'));
 });
```

modified based on @moob's comment

Comment: Exactly this. Could also work with `$('form').submit(...`. No reason why this wouldn't work with AJAX too.

Comment: @moob I updated my answer for the form submit. As for AJAX, I thought the same thing I just didn't want to over complicate things for the OP.

Comment: bammo! thanks a lot to both of you.  I dropped this in and it worked on the first try.